# clearInterval does not get called inside React.useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, setinterval

My React game has a `<Clock/>` component to keep track of the time.

The timer should stop when the game is paused.

I am using Redux to manage the play/pause state, as well as the elapsed time.

```
const initialState = { inProgress: false, timeElapsed: 0 }
```

The `inProgress` state is handled by a button on another component, which dispatches an action to update the store (for the `inProgress` value only).

The `<Clock/>` component increments `timeElapsed` in its `useEffect` hook with `setInterval`. Yet it does not clear.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Clock = ({ dispatch, inProgress, ticksElapsed }) => {

    React.useEffect(() => {

        const progressTimer = setInterval(function(){
            inProgress ? dispatch({ type: "CLOCK_RUN" }) : clearInterval(progressTimer);
        }, 1000)

    }, [inProgress]);

    return (
        <></>
    )
};

let mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
    let { inProgress, ticksElapsed } = state.gameState;
    return { inProgress, ticksElapsed };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null,
)(Clock);
```

Inside `setInterval`, when `inProgress` is `false`, I would expect `clearInterval(progressTimer)` to stop the clock.

Also, there is another issue where leaving out the `[inProgress]` in the `useEffect` hook causes the timer to increment at ridiculous rates, crashing the app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inProgress` is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) for the function passed to setInterval.

You can solve it by clearing the interval in the cleanup function:

```js
const Clock = ({ dispatch, inProgress, ticksElapsed }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const progressTimer = setInterval(function () {
      inProgress && dispatch({ type: 'CLOCK_RUN' });
    }, 500);
    return () =>
      //inprogress is stale so when it WAS true
      //  it must now be false for the cleanup to
      //  be called
      inProgress && clearInterval(progressTimer);
  }, [dispatch, inProgress]);

  return <h1>{ticksElapsed}</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [inProgress, setInProgress] = React.useState(false);
  const [ticksElapsed, setTicksElapsed] = React.useState(0);
  const dispatch = React.useCallback(
    () => setTicksElapsed((t) => t + 1),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setInProgress((p) => !p)}>
        {inProgress ? 'stop' : 'start'}
      </button>
      <Clock
        inProgress={inProgress}
        dispatch={dispatch}
        ticksElapsed={ticksElapsed}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```